# Match minified JavaScript files and html files using globs

Tags: javascript, gulp, del, file-globs

I'm trying to delete all files except for my minified JavaScript files, all which have the .min suffix, and all .html files. This is what I have currently:

```
del([
   'build/app/**/*.!(html|min.js)'
]);
```

This ends up deleting all .js files, including the minified ones, but keeps the .html files. How can I modify this so it deletes all files **except** for the JavaScript files with the .min suffix and the .html files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the `.html` and `.min.js` files separately:

```
del([
 'build/app/**/*.*',
 '!build/app/**/*.html',
 '!build/app/**/*.min.js'
]);
```